# Applications of Kakutani's dichotomy

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, intuition, applications

I'm giving a presentation in my graduate class on [Kakutani's dichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani%27s_theorem_(measure_theory)), as presented in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples.* To my understanding, it gives necessary and sufficient conditions on when two infinite product measures are "equivalent" or mutually singular. However, why is this an important question to figure out? The Wikipedia article I linked to above alludes to an application to Gaussian measures, but I have no experience with infinite-dimensional Gaussian measures, and don't know why one might translate one such measure. Could someone explain some application to me that doesn't require a lot of probability prerequisites?